# 2D vector graphics library to facilitate 2D inverse kinematics

Tags: library, image-processing, game-development, animation, svg

I have looked at many SVG drawing libraries but have not seen any that support or even make implementing 2D IK reasonably efficient. I was excited to find the Godot engine since it has all the support for rigging 2D skeletons and IK for solving them programmatically, but unfortunately the program works in raster (I need the output to be a static SVG).

For example, the problem statement is: given a random combination of vector assets, anchors, and labels, position and rotate them together to form a character.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure about the library aspect of this question, but I have created a few models in the 3D creation program [SolveSpace](https://solvespace.com/index.pl).

On creates vectors, anchors, labels and positions with appropriate constraints. Within those constraints, movement is allowed. A fully constrained model will not allow movement, but that's the creator's responsibility, of course.

From the linked site:

[image: eight bar linkage]

This image represents a segment of Theo Jansen's Strandbeest and allows one to determine the track of the "foot" by turning on the trace feature of the program.

For images, the model is manipulated to the desired position and exported as SVF file format.

I downloaded the mechanisms file from the SolveSpace site and opened one of the more basic models.

[image: Solvespace mechanism model image]

I've turned off the constraints and dimension display and was not able to figure out how to turn them back on, but that's not important. It's been awhile since I've used it at length.

The SVG file that resulted was about as basic as one could ask:

[image: SVG image exported from previous source]

Last two images of my own creation.